# ng2-bootsrap has no exported member 'TAB_DIRECTIVES'

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular, angular2-directives

I am working on angular2 i which i have to use the tab for ui. For that i have trying to use plugin http://valor-software.github.io/ng2-bootstrap/

i have wrote a demoComponent as

```
    import { Component, View, Inject} from 'angular2/core';
    import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';
    import { TAB_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

    // webpack html imports
    let template = require('./tabs-demo.html');

    @Component({
      selector: 'tabs-demo',
      template: template,
      directives: [TAB_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES]
    })
    export class TabsDemo {
      private tabs:Array<any> = [
        {title: 'Dynamic Title 1', content: 'Dynamic content 1'},
        {title: 'Dynamic Title 2', content: 'Dynamic content 2', disabled: true}
      ];

      private alertMe() {
        setTimeout(function () {
          alert('You\'ve selected the alert tab!');
        });
      };
    }
```

here is my template

```
<div (click)="$event.preventDefault()">
  <p>Select a tab by setting active binding to true:</p>
  <p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="tabs[0].active = true">Select second tab</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="tabs[1].active = true">Select third tab</button>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="tabs[1].disabled = ! tabs[1].disabled">Enable / Disable third tab</button>
  </p>
  <hr />
  <tabset>
    <tab heading="Static title">Static content</tab>
    <tab *ngFor="#tabz of tabs"
         [heading]="tabz.title"
         [active]="tabz.active"
         (select)="tabz.active = true"
         (deselect)="tabz.active = false"
         [disabled]="tabz.disabled">

    </tab>
    <tab (select)="alertMe()">
      <template tab-heading>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i> Alert!
      </template>
      I've got an HTML heading, and a select callback. Pretty cool!
    </tab>
  </tabset>

  <hr />

  <tabset [vertical]="true" type="pills">
    <tab heading="Vertical 1">Vertical content 1</tab>
    <tab heading="Vertical 2">Vertical content 2</tab>
  </tabset>

  <hr />

  <p><i>Bootstrap 4 doesn't have justified classes</i></p>
  <tabset [justified]="true">
    <tab heading="Justified">Justified content</tab>
    <tab heading="SJ">Short Labeled Justified content</tab>
    <tab heading="Long Justified">Long Labeled Justified content</tab>
  </tabset>
</div>
```

but when gulp compile its it give the error

[image]

please correct me to run it properly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `TAB_DIRECTIVES` was renamed to `TAB_COMPONENTS`. I made a try with version 0.53 of ng2-bootstrap.

Here is the configuration I used in my `index.html` file regarding SystemJS:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'ng2-bootstrap': {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    },
    map: {
      'ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap'
    }
  });
  System.import('app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: I'm still getting error Could not find input file F:\DemoProjects\TrackMe\client\client\components\home\home.ts. This is probably an issue of gulp-typescript.
Please report it at https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript/issues

Comment: I am using  "ng2-bootstrap": "^0.53.0",

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem to be an error related to ng2-bootstrap... Okay same version as me!